# mapbox-gl-js styles TO Latitude and longitude projection

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Create a leaflet map and crs is EPSG:4326：

```js
const map = L.map(ID, {
   crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
   zoomControl: false,
   center: [34, 108],
   maxZoom: 21,
   minZoom: 3,
   zoom: 3,
});
```

I want to add a mapbox basemap：

```js
L.tileLayer("https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=" + mytoken;, {
  zIndex: 3,
  maxZoom: 21,
  minZoom: 3,
  zoomOffset: 1,
}).addTo(map);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPGoL.jpg)

However the basemap is not in the correct position, how can maobox basemap support EPSG: 4326?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please provide a lot more context about what your app does so far, and what you want it to do. I don't understand "maplet".

Comment: Sorry, the statement is not clear. I updated the question

Comment: Ah, you want to reproject Mapbox tiles dynamically into EPSG 4326? You might be better off at gis.stackexchange.com